# Why is the subquery in this MYSQL query so much slower than this one?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, left-join

I had a script used for getting data related to invoices from clients.  Each invoice and order has a card code associating it with a particular user.  Occasionally users had more than one user account associated with the same card code; in such circumstances I would have to use the user data from the most recently used user account, which I would get using a sub-query.

```
SELECT invoices.*,card.*,client.* 
FROM `orders` 
LEFT JOIN `invoices` ON `invoices`.`invoice_key` =`orders`.`invoice_key` 
LEFT JOIN `cards` `card` ON `card`.`card_code` = `orders`.`card_code` 
LEFT JOIN `users` `client` ON `client`.`id` = (
     SELECT MIN(c.id) c_id FROM `users` `c` 
     WHERE (`card`.`card_code` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci) = `c`.`card_code`
     AND  `c`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY `c`.`last_login` DESC LIMIT 1
)
WHERE `orders`.`date` BETWEEN %start_date% AND %end_date%
```

This worked fine, but then I implemented a system where it was possible for a user to have multiple card codes; to handle this I created another table (usercards) that links users to cards.  Not all users have an entry here; most only need their default card code.

```
SELECT invoices.*,card.*,client.* 
FROM `orders` 
LEFT JOIN `invoices` ON `invoices`.`invoice_key` =`orders`.`invoice_key` 
LEFT JOIN `cards` `card` ON `card`.`card_code` = `orders`.`card_code` 
LEFT JOIN `usercards` ON `usercards`.`card_code` = `card`.`card_code` 
LEFT JOIN `users` `client` ON (`usercards`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL 
   AND `client`.`id` = `usercards`.`user_id`) 
OR (`usercards`.`user_id` IS NULL AND `client`.`id` = (
     SELECT MIN(c.id) c_id FROM `users` `c` 
     WHERE (`card`.`card_code` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci) = `c`.`card_code`  
       AND  `c`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY `c`.`last_login` DESC LIMIT 1)
)
WHERE `orders`.`date` BETWEEN %start_date% AND %end_date%
```

However this caused the query to run *much* slower - like several minutes where before it was less than a second.  I know it has something to do with the sub-query (if I leave that part out and simply join everywhere that client.card_code = card.card_code it works fast, but of course then the data is wrong) but I can't figure out why; I can't see any point that suggests an exponential increase in data that needs to be handled.

There are a lot of orders and invoices, but only a handful of entries in usercards.  Also, usercards.card_code is a unique index.

Comment: You should also post the query plans (`EXPLAIN <query>`). It's much easier to see whats going on using those.

Comment: The answer will be in your EXPLAIN plans (as Vatev hints) but using an OR, particularly in a JOIN clause is usually very bad for performance - try `....UNION DISTINCT....` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many issues for me to give you a straight answer.

- `OR` is a performance killer.  This *may* be a good candidate to convert to `UNION`.  If so, the `IS [not] NULL` clauses may be able to be simplified at the same time.
- `MIN` and `LIMIT 1` are fighting each other.  I suspect you should get rid of the `MIN`.
- Don't use `LEFT` unless you plan for there to be missing rows in the "right" table.
- See my tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on indexes for `usercards`.
- `usercards.user_id IS NULL` seems to be a new condition; does it not change the results?
- Fix the collation of one of the `card_code` columns to match the other.  What you have either defeats index usage or slows things down.
- Consider flipping the query around.  That is, *start* by finding the most recent id, *then* `JOIN` (assuming `LEFT` is not needed) to the other tables.
- `INDEX(card_code, active, last_login, id)` -- in this order.
- (There may be more; fix some of them; then let's discuss further.)
- (Use shorter aliases -- to avoid clutter.)

For more discussion, provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE -- for each table
EXPLAIN SELECT -- for each query being discussed
```